# WordPress e-commerce conditional statement

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using latest version of   [WP e-Commerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) on WP 3.3.1

What I'm trying to do is show some stuff on my sidebar only for shop pages.

Therefore I'm looking for conditional statement similar to the following one but that will work :)

if (shop) {"do it"} else {dont}

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Dom

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've figure this out if anyone ever need it here it is :

```
If not product page: <?php if ('wpsc-product' != get_post_type())  { ?>
         do stuff <?php }?> If product page: <?php if ('wpsc-product' == get_post_type())  { ?>
         do stuff <?php }?>
```